# Updating SameID different cell

Tags: mysql, vb.net

[image]

This is my code where I will update the inventory Quantity anyone know another code like this?

I want to multiple update but different cell!

This is my Inventory which has sameID Different Expiration and as you see in the BatchID 2 has 188 Quantity and BatchID3 has 70 Quantity.

This is my Transaction, Which you see in the 2nd Picture Inventory I have 2 BatchID 2 and 3 in my transaction the BatchID 2 and 3 has merge. Now the quantity in the Inventory BatchID 2 has 188 Quantity and BatchID 3 has 70 Quantity Total of 258 Quantity as you see in the Transaction, Now I want to buy
200pcs of Biogesic 258-200= 58.

Now my problem is the Inventory  as you see I have 2 BatchID 2 and 3
my BatchID 2 it will be 0pcs Quantity and BatchID 3 it will be 58 Quantity 
in my program, when I buy 200pcs biogesic the inventory will be BatchID 2 = -12 and BatchID 3 = 70.

Please help me.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Questions asking for help must include the related code *in the question*.

Comment: Welcome to [SO]. Please paste the actual text of your code into the question using the [edit] button, rather than use an image of the code.